# tomcat manager authentication unauthorized for all user account

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to enter tomcat manger (version 6.0.37 windows 7)...
but all the time authentication failed.my tomcat-user.xml file is

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="tomcat"/>
    <role rolename="role1"/>
    <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
    <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
    <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a user that can access the manager-gui, admin-gui of the Tomcat application. For that you need a user against this role. Simple add this role to any existing user or make a new one as below ( This is what I use for defining a super user for tomcat )

```
<user username="superuser" password="somepass" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,admin-gui,manager-gui"/>
```

Comment: Thx for your comment.....but the result is same yet..I may be done something very silly...I have added these codes bellow:
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="superuser" password="boss" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,admin-gui,manager-gui"/>

Comment: Did you restart tomcat when you made changes in the tomcat-users.xml ?

Comment: sorry....now its working...i just changed full code into:
<tomcat-users>
<user username="superuser" password="boss" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,admin-gui,manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>